# Audio + visual through TCP/IP

Tags: sockets, audio, tcp

im in the process of making an application similar to skype to interact with another computer and i have a few questions.

I know all the basics such as how to send data over tcp etc in the form of an image and audio.

1. How does applications like skype send live audio? Does it litrally record 1 byte of audio, send it and play it and then repeat the process? For me its not instant so i dont see how that would be possible.
2. How would u send string and image through tcp at the same time (video call + chat), would you use multiple ports? i can see how that would be very bad. The way im doing it atm is when i click to recive an image, i set it up to receive an image so it receives properly, if a string got sent at this time for example, it wouldnt work as it cant be converted to an image if you see what im saying. im not sure how else i would do it. I Could send each thing with its type as the beginning for example "string Hello how are you" then decypher the data type through that, but that seems abit tedious and slow.

If anyone could give me an insight, that would be fantastic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for how skype does it, but this should be a starting point:

- Streaming audio/video is usually transported over UDP sockets, not TCP. TCP guarantees delivery whereas UDP is best effort. If you have a temporary connection loss you care more that the video you're receiving is current, not that you receive the whole stream.
- The data is usually compressed (and sometimes encrypted) using a standard compression algorithm after being received from a camera/microphone. Have a look at [H264](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC), which is commonly used to compress video.
- [RTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) is often used to transmit audio/video. It allows multiple types of stream to be combined over a single socket.
- Control traffic is usually sent separately over a different socket, usually TCP. For example SIP which is used for VoIP phones initiates a control connection over a TCP or UDP port (usually 5060). The two ends then negotiate which types of stream will be supported, and how those streams will be sent. For SIP, this will be an RTP stream which is set up on a different UDP port.

Comment: oh wow this sounds more complicated that i thought, i dont suppose you know any simple examples of these i can look at?